# Dart tests are executed after normal code

Tags: unit-testing, testing, dart

I think this is poorly documented (if not a bug).

Dart first completes the code in `main()`, then the tests in functions `test()`.

This code explains:

```
import 'package:test/test.dart';
void main() {
  test('',() {print('1');});
  print('2');
  test('',() {print('3');});
}
```

Output: 213

Is there a way to return an error or suppress the execution of spurious code not pertaining to tests? Or maybe a way to have a lint warning from the analyzer?

Comment: What is your question?  This is expected. `test` *registers* a test case and does not execute it directly.  This is how test order can be randomized and is why you don't need to use `await` on the test itself if it has an asynchronous body.  I agree that it probably should be better documented; I encourage you to [file a bug](https://github.com/dart-lang/test/issues) when you encounter issues.

Comment: Ok. I suppose test should not execute any other code than the tests. I modify the question to ask for a way of suppress it or return an error because of that.